# Moments of an exponential distribution

Tags: statistics, induction, expected-value

Let $f_x(x)=\lambda e^{-\lambda x}$ , $x>0, \lambda >0$ , i need $\mathbb{E}[x^n]$.

I have the following:

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[x^n]
&=\int_{\mathbb{R}} x^n\cdot \lambda e^{-\lambda x} dx\\ &=\int_{0}^{\infty} x^n\cdot \lambda e^{-\lambda x}dx\\
&=x^n\cdot  (-e^{-\lambda x})\Big|_0^{\infty}+\int_0^{\infty} nx^{n-1}\cdot e^{-\lambda x} dx \\
&=[0-0]+\int_0^{\infty} nx^{n-1}\cdot e^{-\lambda x} dx\\
&= \frac{n}{\lambda}\int_0^{\infty}x^{n-1}\cdot\lambda e^{-\lambda x}dx\\
&=\frac{n}{\lambda}\cdot\mathbb{E}[x^{n-1}]
\end{align}

Following the result it seems clear that:

$\displaystyle \mathbb{E}[x^{n-1}]=\frac{n-1}{\lambda}\cdot\mathbb{E}[x^{n-2}]$,

and it seems to have the tendency of:

$\displaystyle \mathbb{E}[x^n]=\frac{n}{\lambda}\cdot \frac{n-1}{\lambda}\cdots=\frac{n!}{\lambda^n}$

Is there a way to test this by induction?

Comment: You can show the formula holds for the base case, then assume it for $E(x^{n-1})$ and show that the same holds for $E(x^{n})$ using the formula that relates $E(x^n)$ and $E(x^{n-1})$ which you derived.

Comment: The inductive proof would proceed as 1) establish the base case ($n=0$), 2) assume that it's true for some arbitrary $n$ (i.e., $E[x^n]=n!/\lambda^n$) and show that it also holds if $n$ is replaced by $n+1$. That's well within the formulas you've set up.

Comment: How does $\mathbb{E}[x^n]$ first become $\int_{\mathbb{R}}x^n\cdot\lambda e^{-\lambda x}\,\mathrm{d}x$ then become $\int_0^\infty\dots$?  You need to be more careful with the negative reals.

Comment: Sice $x>0$ then $\int_0^{\infty}$

Comment: No!  For example, $\int_\mathbb{R}x^n\lambda e^{-\lambda x}\,\mathrm{d}x\neq\int_0^\infty x^n\lambda e^{-\lambda x}\,\mathrm{d}x$.  The LHS integral is $-\infty$ if $n$ is odd (and is $+\infty$ if $n$ is even), whereas the RHS is finite.

Answer (score 1):

There's more than one way to compute the moments of an exponential distribution, and a cute way is via differentiation under the integral sign. We start from the normalization condition: $$\mathbb{E}[1]=\int f_X(x)\,dx = \int_0^\infty \lambda e^{-\lambda x}\,dx=1$$
This rearranges to $\lambda^{-1}=\int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda x}\,dx$. If we differentiate both sides with respect to $\lambda$ (and take for granted we can do so!) we obtain

$$-\lambda^{-2}=-\int_0^\infty x e^{-\lambda x}\,dx\implies \mathbb{E}[X]=\int_0^\infty x\lambda e^{-\lambda x}\,dx=\frac{1}{\lambda}$$
If we instead differentiated twice before rearranging, we obtain

$$2\lambda^{-3}=\int_0^\infty x^2 e^{-\lambda x}\,dx\implies \mathbb{E}[X^2]=\int_0^\infty x^2 \lambda e^{-\lambda x}\,dx = \frac{2}{\lambda^2}$$

More generally, suppose we differentiate our integral representation of $\lambda^{-1}$ a total of $n$ times. Then we obtain

$$n!(-1)^n \lambda^{-n-1} = \int_0^\infty (-x)^n e^{-\lambda x}\,dx\implies \mathbb{E}[X^n]=\int_0^\infty x^n \lambda e^{-\lambda x}\,dx=\frac{n!}{\lambda^n}$$
which was the desired result. It should be noted, though, that there remains an implicit 'proof by induction' in the above; otherwise, the claim that the $n$th derivative indeed gives the result stated has no force. So one as usual needs to check the base case (here $n=0$) and the inductive step (show that validity for $n=k$ also implies validity for $n=k+1$).